# Linux Process details with Swap and Memory Usae

Tags: linux, bash, memory-management, swap

I am checking swap for sqpctl process by using this script:

```
for file in /proc/*/status ; do awk '/VmSwap|Name|Pid/{printf $2 " " $3}END{ print ""}' $file; done | sort -k 5 -n -r | grep sqpctl
```

How to get the output of the above with proper process details? What I mean is, the above script gives me an output like this:

```
[20:00:49][root][~]$ for file in /proc/*/status ; do awk '/VmSwap|Name|Pid/{printf $2 " " $3}END{ print ""}' $file; done | sort -k 5 -n -r | grep sqpctl
sqpctl 11691 8979 0 25092 kB
sqpctl 11878 8979 0 24784 kB
sqpctl 12144 8979 0 20180 kB
sqpctl 11351 8979 0 20084 kB
sqpctl 8976 1 0 1476 kB
sqpctl 16210 8979 0 0 kB
sqpctl 16038 8979 0 0 kB
```

And when I run the below, I get the exact process details spawned by **sqpctl**:

```
[20:10:25][root][~]$ ps -ef | grep sqpctl
rdsdb     8976     1  0 19:27 ?        00:00:00 /u01/sqp/bin/sqpctl -d service start
rdsdb    11326  8979  0 19:34 ?        00:00:11 sqpctl -d sqptaskstr process1
rdsdb    11351  8979  0 19:34 ?        00:00:01 sqpctl -d sqptaskstr process2
rdsdb    11467  8979  0 19:34 ?        00:00:01 sqpctl -d sqptaskstr process3
```

So is there a way I can combine `ps -ef` with the above **swap usage for loop** and get the exact process names. Basically something like this:

```
/u01/sqp/bin/sqpctl        11691 8979 0 25092 kB
process1                   11878 8979 0 24588 kB
process2                   11467 8979 0 24316 kB
process3                   12480 8979 0 21796 kB
process4                   11482 8979 0 21592 kB
process5                   12441 8979 0 21056 kB
process6                   11688 8979 0 20820 kB
```

Answer (score 0):

Will this help you:

```
for file in /proc/*/status ; do awk '/VmSwap|Name/{printf $2 " " $3}END{ print ""}' $file; done | sort -k 2 -n -r | less
```

Sample output:

```
php-cgi 11964 kB
php-cgi 11016 kB
php-cgi 10392 kB
php-cgi 10336 kB
squid 6864 kB
lighttpd 4100 kB
php-cgi 3984 kB
php-cgi 3644 kB
php-cgi 3616 kB
php-cgi 3604 kB
rpc.mountd 3580 kB
```

Using `atop`:

```
atop 3 -P SWP,PRG
```

Comment: Unfortunately no, since the status file don't contain sub-process names which I can only see when i run **ps -ef**. So I wanted to combine both to get the appropriate output.